# Add metadata to commit that persists after rebase/merge

Tags: git

Let's say I have the following workflow:

```
git checkout -b feature
# do some work
git add new_file
git commit -m "finished feature"
git checkout master
# integrate the feature changes into master
git rebase feature
```

When the changes from the feature branch are integrated onto master by way of rebase/merge/rebase & squash, a new commit hash is created on master. Is there any way of mapping the commit hashes on the feature branch to the new commit hash on master branch and vice-versa?

The context is: I have some program that attaches metadata to a commit hash. I want to be able to preserve this metadata to commit relationship even after the developer merges/rebases a branch into/onto master.

Comment: Rebasing `master` on `feature` is a pretty non standard flow.  Can you explain why you are not doing the opposite?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure what the normal work-flow looks like for integrating changes from a branch onto master. Doing `git rebase master` from feature just makes `feature` up to date with `master`

Comment: The typical workflow would be to rebase _feature_ on _master_, then push to master.

Comment: Can you give more details about the metadata you want to attach to a commit ?

Comment: Gerrit uses a `Change-Id` field at the end of the commit message. To avoid changing the hashes, you probably need to tweak the client side to attach that the very first time a commit is created.

Comment: [Docs on Gerrit use of (and creation of) Change-Id](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.2.2/user-changeid.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for other ways to identify commits.

For example :

- When you use an issue tracker, a common way to "link" a commit to an issue ticket is to mention `fixes #xyz` in the commit message ; many standard tools use this to link branches to issues.
- Pull requests (in github, gitlab, azure devops ...) track *branch names* instead of commit ids.

You could use either some specific tokens in your commit messages (these would get automatically brought along when rebasing, cherry-picking ...), or use tags/branches with specific names to point at the commits you are interested in (you would need to update the target tag/branch as a separate action if the commit "moves away").

Answer (score -1):

Here is your current flow:

```
git checkout -b feature
# do some work
git add new_file
git commit -m "finished feature"
git checkout master
# integrate the feature changes into master
git rebase feature
```

Here is an amended flow for getting your changes from `feature` onto `master` in a more standard way.

```
git checkout -b feature
# do some work
git add new_file
git commit -m "finished feature"
git push origin <feature> 
<create pull request - I usually do this on the service itself>
<approve and merge the pull request into master>
```

When using a branching workflow the idea is that the `master`  branch is usually only updated via pull request and rebasing/fixing history occurs in the case of issues. If you are rebasing and updating your master in that fashion you might as well forego the extra steps involved with creating a separate branch and just push commits directly to `master` with the same outcome.